# How to redirect page using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I'm building a page that has a form that's submitting to my database. The form needs to post to the current page to process, but since I'm using this same form on many pages, I would like a way to tell the form to use the user's current page to submit to. I know the code below can get this information, it's what I'm using to send url data to my database for another use.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

I'm just not sure how to use that within the code that loads the page. I suppose I could write something that will pull out the submitted url info that was just submitted to my database and then plug it in, but is there a way to just use the above code to do it? That seems easier, but when I tried plugging it in, it fails and just gives me a "404 not found" error, so I know I'm not doing it correctly.

It just needs to go in the simple form post action code below:

```
<form action="comment_box.php" method="post">
```

I've looked up similar questions, but I couldn't find anything that worked with what I needed, I just got more 404 errors. Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Hii In the code action="comment_box.php']" .. what's the use of closed square bracket??

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I wrote the question, I'll fix that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your posting to the same page the user is on you can do

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Leaving the `form action` blank it will post to what ever the page the form is on.

Not sure what language your using but I assume `php` you then use

```
 <?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
 // form submit button was pressed your php code here
 } else {
 // no form submit button was press do nothing maybe show form html code here
 }
 ?>
```

or what your trying to achieve

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then in `PHP`

```
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>/comment_box.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

for example you have a following code

```
<input type="submit" name="click_me" value="Login">
```

then in the php, you have to check like

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST,$_POST['click_me']) && $_POST['click_me']="Login"){
     //do your stuff
  }
?>
```